# find significant values between groups differences

Tags: matlab

suppose that I a vector where the rows indicate averages of measurements and columns represent group of people.

```
Data = [1.8,1.4, 1.5;
60, 70, 80;
20, 40, 5];
```

Suppose that I've another vector containing the errors in the measurements

```
Error = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4;
20, 30, 10;
10,5,2];
```

I would like to select for each measurement of one group the others that show a significant difference.

So for example

```
    k = 1; 

for i = 1: size(Data,1)

    if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2)) || (Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) < (Data(i,2)-Error(i,2)) )

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i ,1, 2];

      k = k+1;
    end

    if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,3)+Error(i,3)) || (Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) < (Data(i,3)-Error(i,3)))

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i , 1, 3];

      k = k+1;
    end

    if ((Data(i,2)-Error(i,2)) > (Data(i,3)+Error(i,3)) || (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2)) < (Data(i,3)-Error(i,3)))

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i , 2, 3];

      k = k+1;
    end

end
```

My problem is that I don't know in advance the number of if conditions that I should use (the group number is not fixed)...
Is there a way to solve this problem with a general solution?
The results in this example would be

```
selectedpar = [1    1   2
3   1   3
3   2   3]
```

Indicating that for the first measurements the difference between group 1 and 2 is significant, for the 3rd measurements are significant the differences between group 1 and 3 and between group 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you really need the result in that format? It would be easy for example to generate a 3D array indexed as (group,group,measurement)

Comment: You only do the comparison in one direction. For example, `(Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2))`. Is that deliberate? Shoudn't you also check `(Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)-Error(i,2))`?

Comment: well...the second condition should be always true if the first is true so I would obmitt it...
regarding the format...I would prefer the one I suggested because it simplifies my life :) , but yes a 3D array would be fine

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) < (Data(i,2)-Error(i,2))`.

Comment: yes that's true! do you know by any chance how to modify the solution provided by Mohsen to add this condition? thanks

Comment: Maybe adding these two lines right before the `end` (or something similar, I haven't tested): `[I,J]=find(tril(bsxfun(@lt, DP(k,:), DM(k,:).')));` `selectedpar = [selectedpar ; k+zeros(size(I)), J, I];  %#ok<AGROW>`. That is, interchange `DM` and `DP`, change `@gt` to `@lt`, and collect the new resulting `I` and `J` in `selectedpar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun`

```
DM = Data-Error;
DP = Data+Error;
selectedpar = [];
for k=1:size(Data,1)
   [I,J]=find(tril(bsxfun(@gt, DM(k,:), DP(k,:).')));
   selectedpar = [selectedpar ; k+zeros(size(I)), J, I];  %#ok<AGROW>
end
```

You probably can remove the for loop by applying `permute` on `DP` but won't be much of a readable code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I add the other condition that Luis remembered?
((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2))) || (Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) < (Data(i,2)-Error(i,2))

I edited my question accordingly

Comment: can I add those other lines

  [P,H]=find(triu(bsxfun(@gt, DM(k,:), DP(k,:).')));

   selectedpar = [selectedpar ; k+zeros(size(P)), H, P];